# Numpy functions not working in Screen

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using screen in Linux on a machine I've SSHed into. I was having some strange errors with code that was working when not in screen but fails in `screen`.

It looks like numpy is not working properly in screen. For example, on the command-line, while in `screen`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:37:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ceil(1.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ceil'
```

But when not in `screen`, the above runs just fine. I'm unable to find any description of this strange behavior.

Comment: Do you get a _massive_ list output from `print(dir(np))`? If not, what do you see?

Comment: I just closed the screen and opened a new one, and now it seems to be working ... this has happened before though, so next time I will try this.